# Using VS Code Black Formatter extension to format multiple files at once

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

I have the Black Formatter extension configured to format the current file on save. I want to perform a one-time-only action where I format all my python files, as opposed to just the current file. I tried running the command (in the integrated terminal, with venv activated):

`black {my_directory}`

as described in the [documentation](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html). However, I get the "command not found" error. **Trying to run as a script doesn't help.** I could use pip to install a "normal", non-integrated instance of black, but is there a cleaner way to run the above command, without having two copies of black?

**Addendum:** another thing I tried was configuring the Black Formatter args in settings. However, I haven't found how to specify the "SRC" part of the args there, I seem to only be able to set the "[OPTIONS]". Plus, ideally I would prefer not to change these settings, since I only want to do the multiple file formatting action once per project.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with command not found may be that black is not installed in the currently selected interpreter, so you have to use pip install black to install.

Of course, you can also switch to the interpreter installed with black to perform black formatting.